# accessing Objects in Multiple Functions C++

Tags: c++, function, object

I was seperating my `main` function from it's loop by creating a new function `loop`. Now I got the problem that some objects I created in `main` can't be accessed in `loop`. Creating multiple function parameters in `loop` is not an option because it will end in like 30 parameters and more for each Shader and other objects. So I made the objects global:

**main.cpp**

```
Shader light("Shaders/light.shader");
Shader depth("Shaders/depth.shader");
```

**Shader.cpp**

```
Shader::Shader(const std::string& filePath)
{
  source = parseShader(filePath);
  if (shaderGeometry) 
     ID = createShader(source.vertexSource, source.fragmentSource, source.geometrySource);
  else 
     ID = createShader(source.vertexSource, source.fragmentSource);

  use();
}
```

The problem here is that parsing the file paths outside of a function causes an **exception** at:

```
int Shader::createShader(const std::string& vertexShader, const std::string& fragmentShader)
{
program = glCreateProgram(); //<-- HERE
//some further code...
}
```

The `vertexShader` and `fragmentShader` are parsed correctly, so there is no problem.
I guess the `exception` is thrown because the Shaders need to be created inside a function where the GL function pointers are loaded before.

I tried to play around with `extern`. But something like this just leaves a compiling error:

**global variable**

```
extern Shader light;
extern Shader depth;
```

**in the function**

```
int main()
{
Window wnd(width, height);
Shader light("Shaders/light.shader");
Shader depth("Shaders/depth.shader");
wnd.loop();
//some further code
return 0;
}
```

Swithing The `extern Shader light` to the Metod and reversed would end up in the same error from before.
I maybe could access the shader with a getter Method and some kind of Array that safes every vertex, fragment and geometry Shader but maybe there is a more simple way and i just missed something.

Comment: So you seem to think that 30 global objects accessed from many functions are somehow better that 30 function parameters. This is a mistake. The proper solution is to place your "Shader and other object" in an appropriate class, and manipulate instances of that class.

Comment: when you have an error, please let us know what is the error

Comment: Use global variables only when you have a really really good reason to do so. If you can't inject for some reason (in this case you should), use Singletons, but only use Singletons if you have a really really good reason to do so. Every dependency that is not obvious from the interfaces involved is a bug in waiting.

Comment: @n.m. Yeah, your're right. Thinking about the problem how to get the objects into the function without parameters made me forget that the objects won't be less if I use global objects. Reading your comment made me think more clear again. Thanks